# Invite doesn't clear after you use it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Is this intentional? I sent an invite to someone and the Email and Message fields stayed there.

I almost clicked send a second time until I noticed the small message saying it was sent. Is there any way we can get it so the fields reset after you send out an invite?

Answer (score 3):

Invite was a relatively crude hack SE put in for [theoreticalphysics.se](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/) to garner more expertise then the limited private beta. I would be surprised if it does anything more than send the email.

Comment: Thanks. Would nice though if it cleared after use. I don't want to accidentally spam someone.

Comment: Ah, true, but alas and alack, we cannot have everything. (Sometimes it is difficult to get to 15 characters.)

Answer (score 3):

We will now clear the email / message when the invite is successfully sent.

Comment: Great, thank you!